# Vue component fails to render when using mocked fetch response in unit test

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, mocking, fetch-api, bootstrap-vue

I want to test that a BootstrapVue table is rendered correctly based on the data provided by an API. As part of this, I've mocked the `fetch` function. When I provide the data statically using the `loadItems()` method, it works fine - 3 rows are rendered. But when I instead swap it to using the API calling method `getData()` - the rows aren't rendered.

The mocking of `fetch` appears to work as the API response is logged successfully, but it doesn't seem to make it to the data option of the Vue component.

**The Vue component to test:**

```
// MenuTable.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table class="table"
    :items="items" :fields="fields">
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    getData() {
      fetch('https://www.myexampleapi.com/menu', {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          this.items = data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.error = error.message;
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
    loadItems() {
      return [
        { cost: 10, food: 'Spaghetti' },
        { cost: 20, food: 'Pizza' },
        { cost: 30, food: 'Hamburger' },
      ];
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.items = this.loadItems(); // load items statically
    this.getData(); // load items from API
  },
  data() {
    return {
      fields: ['food', 'cost'],
      items: [],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**The test file:**

```
// MenuTable.spec.js
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import MenuTable from '@/components/MenuTable.vue';

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import { BootstrapVue, BButton, BTable, BRow } from 'bootstrap-vue';

// create an extended `Vue` constructor
const localVue = createLocalVue();

// install plugins as normal
localVue.use(BootstrapVue);

describe('Table.vue Buttons Test', () => {
  let wrapper = null;

  // SETUP - run before to each unit test
  beforeEach(() => {
    global.fetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
      json: () => Promise.resolve([
        { cost: 10, food: 'Spaghetti' },
        { cost: 20, food: 'Pizza' },
        { cost: 30, food: 'Hamburger' },
      ]),
    }));

    // render the component
    wrapper = mount(MinimalTable, {
      localVue,
    });
  });

  // TEARDOWN - run after to each unit test
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
    wrapper.destroy();
  });

  it('renders three rows', () => {
    const tableComponent = wrapper.findAll('tbody > tr');
    console.log(tableComponent.length);
    expect(tableComponent.length).toEqual(3);
  });
});
```

I've made sure it's not a case of [shallow mounting](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/common-tips.html#shallow-mounting) by using `mount` instead, and I think I've made sure that the test awaits a response from the API response by using Promises.

How come the API response data can be logged, but not assigned to the `items` data variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're expecting Jest to automatically await the `Promise`s, but you actually have to do that explicitly. You can wait until the next macro tick when the `fetch`'s `Promise`s resolve by awaiting a `setTimeout()` without a specified delay:

```js
it('renders three rows', async () => {
  // wait macro tick when `fetch` Promises resolve
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r))

  const tableComponent = wrapper.findAll('tbody > tr');
  console.log(tableComponent.length);
  expect(tableComponent.length).toEqual(3);
})
```